# Is it possible to create a login page in an asp.net mvc application, that uses Jira credentials?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, jira

I just started a student worker job, and the first task i got was to create a web application login function where you login with your Jira credentials. i chose to use asp.net mvc as it is the only thing i have any experience in when working with web applications (and it is very limited experience).

I used my first couple of days looking around the internet for an answer, but i haven't found anything at all. I am actually also unsure if this is the place to ask, and if it's not, then please tell me so i can take it down again.

But my question is if there is a way to create this login function with jira credentials in asp.net mvc, or should i do something else? if so, could you nudge me in the right direction.

Thank you all.

Comment: https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/deprecation-notice-basic-auth-and-cookie-based-auth/

I can't find an SDK, but they do have an API.

Comment: Do you want to authenticate with Jira cloud or Server?

Comment: @AbdulKarim we have to be either at work, or be connected to the workplaces vpn to access the jira page. So i think Server would be it.

Comment: @JerdineSabio thank you for the link. i will read it through :)

Answer (score 1):

Based on my understanding of how Atlassian products work together, this would be what I realized is happening when Jira is used as Authentication application for sibling products.

Jira server allows you to access its user directory using a special kind of user which is called: [Jira user server](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver/allowing-connections-to-jira-for-user-management-938847045.html) (This is only available for Jira Server).

Your application should sync all users from jira to your application's database (Just the usernames, emails, and displayNames) without the passwords because the passwords are protected and encrypted - Obviously :-).

After you successfully sync all users you should build an authentication method that reads the usernames from your database and authenticate their passwords using Jira API.

And to achieve this you will need to authenticate using rest api. Moreover Jira doesn't have this kind of API to check the username/password validity.

Instead of that, you can make use of Basic Auth in order to check the username, for example if the returned data are valid, that means the username is valid and the way round, you may need to scan the output looking for (X-Seraph-LoginReason) which indicates if the login was failed or no.